# What visa does family need to holiday in New Zealand?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, new-zealand

My friend from the Philippines is on a working visa in New Zealand. He would like to bring his 5-year-old daughter to New Zealand for a holiday. What sort of visa will his daughter need? Her mum will be coming with her, too, only for a visit, not to work.

Comment: And is the mother also a citizen of the Philippines?

Comment: yes mother citizen of philipines.

Answer (score 2):

As visitors from the Philippines do not qualify under New Zealand's [Visa Waiver](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visa-waiver) Program, I believe there are two options available to your friend:

- **Child of Worker Visitor Visa and Partner of Worker Visitor Visa**
  If your friend has a Work Visa (and not a working holiday visa) they could apply for a [Child of a Worker Visitor Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/dependent-children-of-work-visa-holders-visitor-visa) and [Partner of a Worker Visitor Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/partners-of-work-visa-holders-visitor-visa) which allows children (under the age of 19) and partners stay/visit New Zealand for the duration of the Work Visa.  This visa doesn't allow them to work (although that's not likely for the 5-year-old daughter) or study longer than 3 months.

  Note there are some restrictions on who can apply for partner/child of workers visa - Please see [Work visa holder supporting family](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/support-family/support-family).
- **Visitor Visa**
  The [Visitor Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visitor-visa) allows visitors to visit New Zealand for up to nine months visit.  Visitors with this visa also cannot study for more than three months or work.

I am unsure whether Immigration New Zealand would require them to apply for child/partner visa rather than visitor visa due to your friend already living in New Zealand as a worker.  The Visitor Visa would require evidence they can financially support themselves.